# determine location in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to determine the location of a in a array. Im not really sure how to handle this case

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const answers = require('../src/arrays');

describe('arrays', function() {
    let a;

    beforeEach(function() {
        a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
    });

    it('expect determine location of a in array', function(expect) {
        expect(answers.indexOf(a, 3)).to.eql(2);
        expect(answers.indexOf(a, 5)).to.eql(-1);

    });
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure “A” must be an element in “answers”? Your usage here is unclear. What is answers? Why are you looking for an array in “answers”? Is that what you meant to look for?

Comment: I have added both simple (*array of numbers*) and complex (*array of objects*) link as dupe. Please do refer both for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```js
var array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]; 
   
function finding_index(element) { 
  return element === 2; 
} 
  
console.log(array.findIndex(finding_index));
```

Comment: Whilst this is helpful, the question is unclear.